# TSQL command to call *.sql files

Tags: .net, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have several *.sql files with script to create table and sprocs for a new database.

Is there a way to create a TSQL script that could be run from the SQL Query Analyzer that would sequentially call the *.sql files?

Example:
call scrip 01;
call scrip 02;
call scrip 03;
GO

Sorry but I was not able to express my problem properly before.

I need create a Db with many tables, at the moment all scripts are in a unique file (very long).

I use MS Management Studio to run the script in query editor to make the database.

Because this script is very long, I was thinking to split it in different small pieces.

So I would have a main script which will order the execution of separate script to run. example

script1
script2
script3

etc

Do you know hot to do it in TSQL on MS SEL 2008.
thanks once again

I use SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why do you need to run it from the Query analyzer? Have you considered a batch file?

Comment: lets imagine a use a batch file, do you know a command to call other sql files?

Comment: That would depend on which server your running. Try googling osql and sqlcmd.

Comment: try the sp in answer will do work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SqlCmd mode in SSMS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx

:r filename

Not sure if this works in Query Analyzer though.